# how to get the specific word from a string

Tags: php

I am trying to get the last element of a string based on specific character i.e.

```
$a='-test-hello';
```

The output should be `hello`.

Now I want to extract the hello based on the character `-`.
I tried to use `strstr` function in PHP.

But it didn't work. If any one can share any ideas how to accomplish this, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Search php function explode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$a = '-test-hello';
$p = explode('-', $a);
echo end($p);
```